# Rendering colors from a texcoord output

Tags: 2d, monogame, hlsl, isometric, fragment-shader

I'm trying to implement a faster alternative to super-sampling for my isometric 2d monogame game (for when the view is zoomed out). The idea was that I would render the texture coordinates to the render target like so:

```
output.Color = float4(input.TexCoord.xy, 0, 1);
```

[image: render-target with texture coordinates as output]

...And then I would sample the sprite using the surrounding pixels' texture coordinates to get an anti-aliased color. I first tried my method by only sampling the original pixel to see if I could replicate the original output first, but I can't make it work. This is the result I got:

```
output.Color = sprite.Sample(spriteSampler, tex.Sample(texSampler, input.TexCoord).xy);
```

[image: render-target with colors sampled from the sprite using the previous render-target]

I used point filtering, I tried disabling mipmaps, I tried offsetting the texture coordinates, and it just doesn't work. For some reason the sampled texture coordinates are linearly interpolated, which gives out nonsense texture coordinates at the edges of textures, producing black lines.

However, if I zoom in close enough and align the camera somewhat, I get the correct output:

[image: render-target with colors]

So what is causing those black lines? What can I do to remove them?

**Additional info:**

Sprite dimensions:   2048 x 2048

Render target format for texcoords:   Vector2

Vertex declaration for the screen quad (not indexed):

```csharp
vertices = new VertexPositionTexture[6];
vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(-1, 1, 0);
vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(-1, -1, 0);
vertices[3].Position = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
vertices[4].Position = new Vector3(1, -1, 0);
vertices[5].Position = new Vector3(-1, -1, 0);

vertices[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0);
vertices[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0);
vertices[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1);
vertices[3].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0);
vertices[4].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1);
vertices[5].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1);
```

This is the code that converts the the computed coordinates for the blocks to screen space:

```
float4 PixelToScreen(float4 position)
{
    position.x = position.x * ((scale * 2) / resolution.x) - 1;
    position.y = position.y * ((scale * 2) / resolution.y) + 1;

    return position;
}
```

Comment: How big is the texture you're sampling from? What format is the render texture you're writing your texture coordinates into? Can you show us your code so we can check details like how you've ensured 1:1 pixel to texel alignment between your passes?

Comment: @DMGregory I added some info

Answer (score 1):

You could try padding your sub textures with zero alpha for the near-misses in sampling.
 You could also try `glSetTexParameterI(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S , GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)` or something similar.